Как отключить сохранение сессии от Keycloak для web приложения?
В качестве провайдера oauth 2 использую Keycloak для web приложения.
Я заметил, что при авторизации, он сохраняет сессию и при повторной авторизации в приложении окна с вводом логина, пароля нет, происходит сразу редирект.
Можно это отключить? Ведь приложение и так сохраняет токен в лок. хранилище, а сохранение сессии и от Keycloak это уже лишнее.
Или можно обойтись и им и не сохранять токен?

Вы как-нибудь сообщаете KeyCloak, что предыдущая сессия закончилась? Если нет, то у него нет шанса узнать что запускаете "повторную" авторизацию. Он не отличает "повторные" авторизации от обычной работы с токеном внутри одной сессии вашего приложения.
